# How to extract the source code from .exe file which is created by using install shield 2009

Tags: installation, installshield-2009

How to extract the source code from .exe file which is created by using install shield 2009?

I am using install shield 2009 . I have .exe file which is obtained from install shield by running our code . But now i have lost the code and i have only the .exe file(which the output) with me . Is there any way to retrieve the source code from .exe file which i have now . Please help me on this .

I have tried most software's available on web but could not accomplish the necessary

Comment: Can someone please guide me ?

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, it is not possible to obtain source code from object code (.exe).
Even if possible, it can only be partially recovered because of compiler optimization.

Try to search about reverse engineering on this topic.